# Deleted ang0 and ang1

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I accidentally deleted ang0 and ang1 from my PC. I was dual-booting ubuntu with Windows 8 as default. How do I repair it? I installed ubuntu with UNetBootIn.

Answer (score 2):

okay i faced the same problem and here's what i did:

1. boot into windows (7 or 8)
2. open EasyBCD (or install if you dont already have it)
3. delete any existing Linux/Ubuntu entries from it.
4. create a new entry for ubuntu and choose GRUB2.
5. save and exit.

solved :)